# How to move object inside another object in the same array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 3 arguments in a move function those are list,source and destination.
List is here :

```
const list = [
      {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Folder 1',
        files: [
          { id: '2', name: 'File 1' },
          { id: '3', name: 'File 2' },
          { id: '4', name: 'File 3' },
          { id: '5', name: 'File 4' },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: '6',
        name: 'Folder 2',
        files: [{ id: '7', name: 'File 5' }],
      },
    ];
```

in a given function I should enter the source and destination and I could move for example `move(list, '4', '6')` then I expect file with id `4` moved to the folder which has id `6`.

Like that :

```
const result = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Folder 1',
    files: [
      { id: '2', name: 'File 1' },
      { id: '3', name: 'File 2' },
      { id: '5', name: 'File 4' },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    name: 'Folder 2',
    files: [
      { id: '7', name: 'File 5' },
      { id: '4', name: 'File 3' },
    ],
  },
];
```

I moved it  `Received: {"files": [{"id": "7", "name": "File 5"}, {"id": "4", "name": "File 3"}], "id": "6", "name": "Folder 2"}` but I couldn't delete the value that id is 4.

Here is my code

```
let copyList =list.slice();

 const filteredVal =  copyList[0].files.find((file: { id: Object; })=> { 

  return file.id == source
 } );// 2-3-4-5

//  if (copyList[0].files.id === source){
//   delete copyList[0].files.source
//  } -> Doesn't work.


 copyList[1].files.push(filteredVal);

 return copyList[1]
```

I am using typescript also I'm testing it with jest I don't wait for the direct answers just I need steps to go or any need to write from scratch with another technique.

Comment: should be able to move 1 to 7 also ? EX -Move(List, 1,7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, I leave you some comments

```js
function move(list, fileId, folderId) {
  // This does not copy the objects inside list, prefer something like JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(list)) to do a deep copy
  const copyList = list.slice();
  // Get the files from the folder where is located your fileId
  const { files: originFiles } = copyList.find(({ files }) => files.some(({ id }) => id === fileId))
  // Get the index of the file to move
  const fileToMoveIndex = originFiles.findIndex(({ id }) => id === fileId)
  // Find the destination folder with the folderId
  const destinationFolder = copyList.find(({ id }) => id === folderId)
  // Add the file in the destination folder
  destinationFolder.files.push(originFiles[fileToMoveIndex])
  // Remove the file from it origin folder
  originFiles.splice(fileToMoveIndex, 1)
  return destinationFolder
}
move(list, '4', '6');
console.log(list);
```

```html
<script>
const list = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Folder 1',
    files: [
      { id: '2', name: 'File 1' },
      { id: '3', name: 'File 2' },
      { id: '4', name: 'File 3' },
      { id: '5', name: 'File 4' },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    name: 'Folder 2',
    files: [{ id: '7', name: 'File 5' }],
  },
];
</script>
```

Comment: Because the originalList is modified ? I left him a comment to explain it.

Comment: I changed your console.log to show it does work, but you still modify the original. OP seems to want to copy

Comment: And if you are talking about the return, he wanted to return the folder were the file is transfered, let you check and verify your own code

Comment: I do not see OP wanted to return the folder... The code he posted  seems that he wants to return the copy of the list with the modifications

Answer (score 0):

Here is the long way around without testing if the `id` was found

NOTE how I copy the array - slice will not make a deep copy.

```js
const move = (list, from, to) => {
  const arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(list)); // safer than slice
  const fromFiles = arr.find(({files}) => files.some(({id}) =>  id === from))?.files; // array of source files
  if (!fromFiles || fromFiles.length === 0) return null;
  const fromFile = fromFiles.splice(fromFiles.findIndex(({id}) =>  id === from),1);  // remove and return source file
  const toFiles = arr.find(({id}) => id === to)?.files;
  if (!toFiles || toFiles.length === 0) return null;
  toFiles.push(fromFile); // push the file to the destination array.
  return arr
  
}
console.log("--- 1 ---\n"); 
console.log(move(list, '4', '6')); // new array
console.log("--- Original --- \n"); 
console.log(list); // old unaffected array
console.log("--- 2 ---\n"); 
console.log(move(list, '8', '6')); // from not found
console.log("--- Original --- \n"); 
console.log(list); // old unaffected array
console.log("--- 3 ---\n"); 
console.log(move(list, '7', '6')); // to not found
console.log("--- Original --- \n"); 
console.log(list); // old unaffected array
```

```html
<script>
const list = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Folder 1',
    files: [
      { id: '2', name: 'File 1' },
      { id: '3', name: 'File 2' },
      { id: '4', name: 'File 3' },
      { id: '5', name: 'File 4' },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    name: 'Folder 2',
    files: [{ id: '7', name: 'File 5' }],
  },
];
</script>
```

Comment: @3limin4t0r Why would files.some fit better? Here it will work the same as some

Comment: I did not realise which "find" you meant. I have changed to some

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a mutating solution, here is one that is fairly easy to understand.

Loop through all files in every folder until you find the file that matches the provided `sourceFileID`. Then search the folder that matches the provided `destinationFolderID`. If both are found, remove the file from the source and add it to the destination.

```js
function move(folders, sourceFileID, destinationFolderID) {
  // intentional `var` usage, these variables are accessible outside of the for-block
  for (var sourceFolder of folders) {
    var iFile = sourceFolder.files.findIndex(file => file.id == sourceFileID);
    if (iFile >= 0) break;
  }
  
  if (!(iFile >= 0)) return; // source file not found
  
  const destinationFolder = folders.find(folder => folder.id == destinationFolderID);
  
  if (!destinationFolder) return; // destination folder not found
  
  const [file] = sourceFolder.files.splice(iFile, 1);
  destinationFolder.files.push(file);
}

const list = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Folder 1',
    files: [
      { id: '2', name: 'File 1' },
      { id: '3', name: 'File 2' },
      { id: '4', name: 'File 3' },
      { id: '5', name: 'File 4' },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    name: 'Folder 2',
    files: [{ id: '7', name: 'File 5' }],
  },
];

move(list, "4", "6");
console.log(list);
```

```css
div.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% }
```

Comment: Why the loop. That is so inelegant

Comment: @mplungjan The loop is there to both find the `sourceFolder` and the index of the relevant file. It might not be the most elegant, but it is more efficient than your solution. You have to use `files.find()` once to find the folder, then use `files.findIndex()` to find the index in the folder. Thus iterating `files` twice. This solution does both steps at once.